# SharePoint 2013 License mapping for Anonymous Users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-web-apps, licensing

I have a single office web apps server to which my SharePoint 2013 environment is bound. I have just turned on office web apps edit functionality for my intranet/extranet SharePoint 2013 farm.

To do that, I used New-SPUserLicenseMapping and assigned the "OfficeWebAppsEdit" License to a particular Security Group for intranet. When you assign the "OfficeWebAppsEdit" License to a particular Security Group, everyone else has to be assigned a standard/Enterprise licence so that they can access other Enterprise features such as Infopath Forms. I assigned the Enterprise Licence to remaining Domain Users and everything is working as expected for Internal Users.

I have another webapplication which is extended to Internet Zone and Anonymous users have access to it. The web application uses some infopath forms for anonymous users. Now, on that internet facing application, the anonymous users are getting an error that they are not licensed to use Infopath Forms.

Now my question is:

How to I assign an Enterprise License to Anonymous users ? Or How do I resolve the anonymous users not being able to access infopath forms.

This is how I did it for a Security Group.

```
$a=New-SPUserLicenseMapping -SecurityGroup yoursecuritygroup -License Enterprise
$a | Add-SPUserLicenseMapping
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot the enforce user license policy on the anonymous users because one of the requirement is user associate to AD security group.

> new User License Enforcement capabilities that enable the definition,
>   assignment, and mapping of licenses to users associated with specific
>   Active Directory security groups.

Read more here: [Introduction to User License Enforcement in SharePoint Server 2013 [Updated]](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2012/11/12/introduction-to-user-license-enforcement-in-sharepoint-server-2013-updated/)

2nd thing, OWA is not work well when you have mix environment( authenticated and anonymous) and it is highly recommended don't use OWA with anonymous access.
Check this one for same kind of issue http://www.wictorwilen.se/an-explanation-to-to-start-seeing-previews-please-log-on-by-opening-the-document-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: Thanks. I do not need OWA for anonymous users. It is just the effect of applying OWA editing for AD users that the remaining users of the farm needs to be assigned an enterprise license to use features like Infopath. The infopath forms work for anonymous users with no licensing in place, but as soon as I apply licensing to an AD Security Group, the side effect is that the infopath forms for anonymous users stop working. Is there a way that infopath forms keep working with licensing on

Comment: I am not sure about it, i think in this case you may be open a support case as i am seeing this is limitation of the product